# What are some tips for processing large files in Java

Tags: java, nio, large-files

I need to perform a simple grep and other manipulations on large files in Java.  I am not that familiar with the Java NIO utilities, but I am assuming that is what I need to use.  What resources or helpful tips do you have for reading/writing large files.  Also, I am working on a SWT application and need to display parts of that data within a text area on a GUI.

Comment: What type of files are we talking about here? I'm guessing textfiles, but it's a bit unclear. What kind of manipulation are you looking to do? Please, be more detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.io.RandomAccessFile` uses long for file-pointer offset so should be able to cope. However, you should read a chunk at a time otherwise overheads will be high. `FileInputStream` works similarly.

Java NIO shouldn't be too difficult. You don't need to mess around with `Selector`s or similar. In fact, prior to JDK7 you can't select with files. However, avoid mapping files. There is no unmap, so if you try to do it lots you'll run out of address space on 32-bit systems, or run into other problems (NIO does attempt to call GC, but it's a bit of a hack).

Comment: I agree with avoiding the mapping of files. I have run into memory usage issues due to the resources of mapped files not being released when the FileChannel is closed.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are doing is reading the entire file a chunk at a time, with no special processing, then nio and `java.io.RandomAccessFile` are probably overkill.  Just read and process the content of the file a block at a time.  Ensure that you use a `BufferedInputStream` or `BufferedReader`.

If you have to read the entire file to do what you are doing, and you read only one file at a time, then you will gain little benefit from nio.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little bit off topic: Have a look on [VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) by apache. It's originally meant to be a library for hiding the ftp-http-file-whatever system behind a file system facade from your application's point of view. I mentioning it here because I have positive experience with  accessing large files (via ftp) for searching, reading, copying etc. (large in that context means > 15MB) with this library.